# Unique dictionary values - print keys

Tags: python, hash-map

I'm working on this code for exam in an MIT Python course. It's working but I'm trying to improve it. What could I do, and what should I avoid?

```
aDict = {   0: 1, 
     1: 2, 
     2: 2, 
     4: 2, 
     5: 2,
            6: 3,
     7: 2}


values=list(aDict.values())
keys=list(aDict.keys())
value_copy=values[:]
uniqe=[]


m=0

for value in value_copy:
    m+=1
    if value in value_copy[m:]:
        while(values.count(value)):
            try:
                values.remove(value)
            except:
                pass

for val in values:
    uniqe.append(keys[value_copy.index(val)])

uniqe.sort()

print (uniqe)
```

Comment: If you're trying to look up keys based on dictionary values, your dictionary might be backwards.

Comment: Your indentation of `aDict` is ugly, make it pretty. Never use a catch-all `except` block. Don't use variable names similar to function names or keywords.

Answer (score 4):

A more efficient way (in terms of lines of code) of doing the same thing would be to use this code. The code declares a new dictionary `countMap` and then loops over the items in `aDict`. The first loop increases the entry in `countMap` that corresponds to the current value of `aDict` which is being evaluated and then increases the value in `countMap` if it's already been found but if it hasn't then it sets the corresponding value in `countMap` to 0 and then increments the value (initially setting every value to 1 or if it's already been found then incrementing it). The second loop only adds values within `countMap` to the list `uni` if there values equal 1 (if the current entry is unique).

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032281/python-finding-keys-with-unique-values-in-a-dictionary):

```
aDict = {
        0: 1, 
        1: 2, 
        2: 2, 
        4: 2, 
        5: 2,
        6: 3,
        7: 2}

countMap = {}
for v in aDict.values():
    countMap[v] = countMap.get(v,0) + 1
uni = [ k for k, v in aDict.items() if countMap[v] == 1]    
print(uni)
```